# Push an associative item into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I correct the following code?

```js
var arr = [];
var name = "name";
var val = 2;
arr.push(val); //works , but not associative
arr[name] = val; //does not work
console.log(arr);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz8pK/)

Comment: It does assign val to the key "name", but in JS: console.log(arr.name);

Answer (score 124, accepted):

To make something like [associative array in JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) you have to use objects.
​

```js
var obj = {}; // {} will create an object
var name = "name";
var val = 2;
obj[name] = val;
console.log(obj);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bz8pK/1/

Comment: You should rename `arr` to `obj`. Because it's an object, not an array.

Comment: You know, at times we get so focused on complex solutions that we forget the simple ones. arr[name] = val; 5 years later thank you brother. Combined with a for cycle you can shove variables one after another all day

Comment: Using this method doesn't do a proper push as the question implies.  The array gets built in the order that it wants to instead of pushing the new value onto the end.

Comment: @jgreep What is the question implying? Where is any reference to the order of the array? I don't follow your comment.

Comment: @VisioN The question says "push."  That implies a formal stack structure with a pop and push, where order is important.  Although, I concede that the context of the question shows that order is not a priority.  In that respect, your answer is appropriate and the question is misleading.  I provided an answer below that solves the problem using a stack approach.

Comment: @jgreep I think in StackOverflow you don't need to read the majority of questions literally. "push" here implies the intention of adding an item to the "associative array". The term probably comes from PHP, where they use "associative arrays" to describe mappings. It was quite clear from the context that the author didn't mean any sequenced data structures, like stacks, deques, or queues. Your answer could be a good contribution to demonstrate how to preserve the order, but you need to give a clear message about it in the description.

Answer (score 28):

JavaScript doesn't have associate arrays. You need to use Objects instead:

```
var obj = {};
var name = "name";
var val = 2;
obj[name] = val;
console.log(obj);​
```

To get value you can use now different ways:

```
console.log(obj.name);​
console.log(obj[name]);​
console.log(obj["name"]);​
```

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript **has** associative arrays.

Here is a working snippet.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myArray = [];
  myArray['thank'] = 'you';
  myArray['no'] = 'problem';
  console.log(myArray);
</script>
```

They are simply called objects.

Comment: This is not an array. The presence of non-numeric keys renders this an object literal. See for yourself: `console.log(typeof myArray);`. Also, the `length` property will not count these non-numeric keys as part of the array: `console.log(myArray.length);` returns `0`. Add `myArray[0] = 'see';`, then run again, it returns `1`.

Comment: You guys dipute about naming? Is it an object? An array? Well, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp calls it an Array Object.
:))

Answer (score 2):

If you came to this question searching for a way to push to the end of an associative array while preserving the order, like a proper stack, this method should work. Although the output is different than the original question, it is still possible to iterate through.

```js
// Order of entry altered
let obj = {}; //  will create an object
let name = "4 name";
let val = 4;
obj[val] = name;
name = "7 name";
val = 7;
obj[val] = name;
name = "2 name";
val = 2;
obj[val] = name;
console.log(obj);

// Order of entry maintained for future iteration
obj = []; //  will create an array
name = "4 name";
val = 4;
obj.push({[val]:name}); // will push the object to the array
name = "7 name";
val = 7;
obj.push({[val]:name});
name = "2 name";
val = 2;
obj.push({[val]:name});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Another method for creating a JavaScript associative array

First create an array of objects,

```
 var arr = {'name': []};
```

Next, push the value to the object.

```
  var val = 2;
  arr['name'].push(val);
```

To read from it:

```
var val = arr.name[0];
```

Comment: This only works if 'name' is defined.  If you want to push a new entry onto the object, this will not work.