# how to add array into array's and as its property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Add second and third array as main's array properties

http://jsfiddle.net/eRj9V/

```
var main = [{
    'id': 1,
    //'second':[
    //     {'something':'here'},
    //{'something':'here 2'}
    // ],

    /*'thrid' : [
    {'something':'here too '},
    {'something':'here too 2'}
]
*/
}]

var second[{
    'something': 'here'
}, {
    'something': 'here 2'
}]

var thrid[{
    'something': 'here too '
}, {
    'something': 'here too 2'
}]
```

One more question, I'm building single page application, should I do this at the back or front end better?

Comment: Missing assignment `=` in `var second` and `var third`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this to add them -

```
var second = [{
    'something': 'here'
}, {
    'something': 'here 2'
}]

main['second'] = second;
```

For more help-

[how to push associative item into array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550158/how-to-push-associative-item-into-array-in-javascript)

Comment: what if I do not want to mention 'second'? I mean the associative name, I want to push it as property?

Comment: use javascript push() method for array

Answer (score -1):

Simple :

```
var second = [{
    'something': 'here'
}, {
    'something': 'here 2'
}]

var third = [{
    'something': 'here too '
}, {
    'something': 'here too 2'
}]

var main = [{
    'id': 1,
    'second':second,
    'third' : third
}]

// or 
main['second'] = second;
main['third'] = third;
```

Such an object can be returned from the backend / or created on the frontend as shown.