# JavaScript array["index"].push() doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ar = [];
ar["index"].push("data1");
ar["index"].push("data2");
ar["index3"].push("data5");
ar[55].push("data7");

console.log(ar);
</script>
```

I get: **TypeError: ar.index is undefined**

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to push associative item into array in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550158/how-to-push-associative-item-into-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this

```
ar["index"].push("data1");
```

javascript tries to push `"data1"` into an array. The problem is that it expects an array, which `ar["index"]` is not as it is undefined.

You first need to initialize it

```
ar["index"] = [];
ar["index"].push("data1");
```

`push()` documentation [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 0):

just make it like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ar = [];
ar.push("data1");
ar.push("data2");
ar.push("data5");
ar.push("data7");

console.log(ar);
</script>
```

Here is dev reference api => [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: The second approach should use an object instead of an array.

Comment: @ShirAzi then `all_line_path[data.line_id]` should return array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ar = [];
    ar["index"] = data1;
    ar["index"] = data2;
    .........
    ........

    console.log(ar);
</script>
```

Comment: In this case, this should be an object and not an array.

Comment: No this will also work for array ..........you can check http://jsfiddle.net/7j5om9ee/

Comment: It will work for an array, but not in every way intended. So for example `ar.length` will still be 0 after your assignment. Array is just a special case of an object. If you do not use any of the added methods, just use a plain object.

Answer (score 0):

Array accepts the method push

What you wanna do is direct access, like a dictionary style... in this case, setting will just do the trick.

```
var ar = [];
ar["index"] = "data1";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying create an array of arrays you must check that the "inner" array exists. Something along the lines of this:

```
if(ar['index'] == null) {
    ar['index'] = [];
    ar['index'].push("data1");
} else {
 ar['index'].push("data1");
}
```